# Oracle Connection through Visual Studio 2013

Tags: oracle, ssis

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Connectors v2.0 for Oracle (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29283) to connect to an Oracle database through SSIS.

I am running Windows 7 SP 1 (64-bit), with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I have installed the connector:

[image: Connector for Oracle by Attunity]

I also have the 32-bit Oracle client installed on my machine for PL/SQL Developer - it works.

But when I create a package in VS 2013 and try to connect to the Oracle DB - I don't have the option to connect to the Oracle source:either by trying to add a new connection through the connection manager or creating a Data Flow Task and dragging the Oracle Source from "Other Sources" within the data flow.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need the Microsoft Connectors v3.0 for Oracle to work with VS 2013.
[Microsoft Connectors v3.0 for Oracle and Teradata](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44582)